# How to efficiently draw lines in the 3D surface of plotly.js?

Tags: surface, plotly.js

I used the surface in the plotly.js library to draw a 3D surface, and I needed to draw a curve on the surface dynamically and efficiently (actually the curve corresponding to the cross-section of the 3D surface, and the drawn action is associated with the mouse movement event).

I tried the update() function and restyle() function. Each time the update() is executed, the 3D surface and cross-section curve will be re-rendered together, costing about 500ms, which is difficult to meet our needs. The restyle() can only update the data corresponding to the curve, but the 3D surface will disappear strangely. This confuses me.

I think that there is a corresponding contour attribute of Surface Traces， which can realize contour lines drawing almost without delay. I am thinking about whether I can learn from contour drawing to help solve the problem of cross-section curve drawing. But I don't quite understand the mechanism of contour drawing.

Thank you in advance

Here is the 3D surface original version: https://plotly.com/javascript/3d-surface-plots/

[This is the effect I expect. The white curve (cross-section curve) on the surface needs to be drawn dynamically. Using update() can achieve the effect, but it takes too long.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A8WT.jpg)[Using restyle() only updates the data of the cross-section curve, which can meet the demand in terms of efficiency, but the 3D surface disappears.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJarW.jpg)[The contours attribute can efficiently display contour lines (the green lines in the Picture) on the 3D surface. Can I learn from this drawing method?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fsuj.jpg)